# Understanding Proof Lang Linear Algebra p. 92

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I’m currently studying the notion of the matrix associated with a linear map with respect to certain bases. I do not understand at all Lang’s proof for Theorem 3.6. The theorem’s statement is as follows:

> Let $F:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map, and let $B$, $B’$ be bases of $V$. Then there exists an invertible matrix $N$ such that
> $M^{B’}_{B’}(F)=N^{-1}M^B_B(F)N.$ In fact, we can take $N=M^{B’}_B(id).$

His proof is the following:

> Applying Theorem 3.2 step by step, we find that $M^{B’}_{B’}(F)=M^B_{B’}(id)M^B_B(F)M^{B’}_B(id).$

I’ve been trying to figure out what that one step was that miraculously proved the statement, since it must have been so obvious it didn’t merit any further explanation. My issue is that “Theorem 3.2” is a typo and is referring to Corollary 3.2, which states that:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $B$, $B’$ be bases of $V$. Let $v\in V.$ Let $X_A(v)$ mean the (column) coordinate vector of $v$ in terms of some basis $A$. Then $X_{B’}(v)=M^B_{B’}(id)X_B(v).$

I have no idea how this was employed in proving Theorem 3.6. Any guidance, or preferably a hint, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Corollary 3.2 he proves that the matrix corresponding to a change of basis can be interpreted as the matrix of the identity function from the origin to the final basis. In the Theorem he is just using that you can change the reference in which the matrix of a linear function is expressed using the former matrix. The idea is that if you have the matrix of a linear function in a basis B and you are given a vector in basis B’ you can take it to B, apply the operation, and bring back the result to B’.

Comment: @Zanzag I don’t understand what you mean. Could you maybe explain more specifically what you’re trying to say in your last sentence? Apologies for the misinterpretation.

Comment: @Zanzag I now get it. Thank you.